# HtmlAgilityPack to get data from HTML table in C#

Tags: c#, html-table, html-agility-pack

Using HtmlAgilityPack, how to get data from input hidden values and tr, td rate  in C# from HTML table?

I need to input hidden values to tr, td rate. How to get that information my below html table?

```
<table>
    <caption>
        <div id="cal_nav"
             class="float_right">
            <ul class="inline">
                <li>
                    <a href="#"
                       onClick="changeRatesView('calendar')">Calendar View</a>
                </li>
                <li id="previous"
                    class="first">
                    <a title="September"
                       -  "2015"
                       href="#"
                       onClick="searchPrevMonthAvailability()">&nbsp;</a>
                </li>
        </div>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Occupancy</th>
            <th>Net Rate</th>
            <th>Sell Rate</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="rateid"
               value="234154166">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>single</td>
            <td>1652</td>
            <td>2500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>single</td>
            <td>1454</td>
            <td>4344</td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="rateid"
               value="234154134">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>single</td>
            <td>1652</td>
            <td>2500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>single</td>
            <td>1454</td>
            <td>4344</td>
        </tr>
        <input type="hidden"
               name="rateid"
               value="234154145">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>single</td>
                <td>1652</td>
                <td>2500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>single</td>
                <td>1454</td>
                <td>4344</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**MY Linq code:**

```
var tds= (from td in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
select td).ToList()[2].ChildNodes[2];

var trer = tdsyh.SelectNodes("//input[@type='hidden' and     @name='rateid']|tr").Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you want to ask here?

Comment: How to get input hidden values and tr, td rate values from  hmtl table using HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var hiddenFields = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input").Where(_ => _.GetAttributeValue("type", "").Equals("hidden") && _.Name.Equals("rateid"));
```